UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable in python
I have the below python code like below.
From a date I am trying to findout first and last calendar days of the month.
import datetime
import calendar

def calendar_days_month(run_date):
    """
    :param run_date: date on which the process is running
    :return:
    """
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(run_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    first_calendar_day = d.replace(day=1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    res = calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)[1]

    if len(str(d.month)) == 1:
      last_month = '%02d' % d.month

    last_calendar_day = str(d.year) + '-' + str(last_month) + '-' + str(res)
    return first_calendar_day, last_calendar_day
    
abc_date = '2024-10-31'

test_1, test_2 = calendar_days_month(abc_date)
print(test_2)
print(test_1)

I am getting the below error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    test_1, test_2 = calendar_days_month(abc_date)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/main.py", line 16, in calendar_days_month
    last_calendar_day = str(d.year) + '-' + str(last_month) + '-' + str(res)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'last_month' where it is not associated with a value

How can I fix this error?

What is the value of last_month if len(str(d.month)) is not exactly 1?

if len(str(d.month)) == 1 if that is false, the assignment last_month = '%02d' % d.month is not executed, therefore the variable last_month does not exist.

To avoid the horror show created if you follow the commented suggestion to use globals, here's how you ensure last_month has a valid value regardless of the length of d.month as a string:
import datetime
import calendar


def calendar_days_month(run_date):
    """
    :param run_date: date on which the process is running
    :return:
    """
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(run_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    first_calendar_day = d.replace(day=1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    res = calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)[1]

    last_month = '%02d' % d.month if len(str(d.month)) == 1 else d.month

    last_calendar_day = str(d.year) + '-' + str(last_month) + '-' + str(res)
    return first_calendar_day, last_calendar_day


abc_date = '2024-10-31'

test_1, test_2 = calendar_days_month(abc_date)
print(test_2)
print(test_1)

The key change being:
last_month = '%02d' % d.month if len(str(d.month)) == 1 else d.month

But that's just making it explicit. This works as well:
last_month = '%02d' % d.month

Since there's nothing wrong with turning a two digit value into a zero-padded length two string either.
Then again, why not cut through the chase and go:
last_calendar_day = f'{d.year}-{d.month:02}-{res}'

Or for that matter, why not just:
last_calendar_day = d.replace(day=res).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

Keep going and you end up with something like this:
def calendar_days_month(run_date: str) -> tuple[str, str]:
    """
    Give date strings for the first and last day of the month in which run_date falls
    :param run_date: string representation of date as '%Y-%m-%d' 
    :return:
    """
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(run_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    return (
        d.replace(day=1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        d.replace(day=calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)[1]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    )

My comment there would be that the function would probably be more useful if it accepted a date, and returned a tuple of dates, since the specific date format used makes its use very limited, and you typically only want to do that type of conversion just before printing it, or just after reading an input.
A more general note, your datetime.datetime.strptime is not wrong, but it's common practice to from datetime import datetime to avoid the repetition.
